# Is there a periodic table for knots?

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, knot-theory

When I see knot tables, I have two feeling: ah, it's beautiful, and... painful.

I don't see how knots are ordered in the knot table, the way to go from one knot of a certain crossing number to another seems to be completely random. But I would guess there are some order? For example, why are the [Perko pair](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perko_pair) put next to each other even before people knew they are the same?

In short, if the word "periodic table" seems confusing, my real question is, how are the knots in knot table ordered?

Comment: If you're referring to the knot table at the back of Rolfsen's book (sometimes also called the Conway table) the ordering is first on the number of crossings and then if the knots have the same number of crossings they're listed in the order they were discovered. 

Comment: Errr... that's like the list of chemical elements before the periodic table.

Comment: Not really.  If you want to make that analogy, you have to talk about a specific "periodic" quality of knots.  What would that quality be?  Your question seems to be based on the idea that knots *should* be somehow comparable to atoms, but you haven't told us *why* you think that should be. 

Comment: There are a bunch of ways you could try to make some kind of periodic table of knots.  Using geometrization you'd first have the three primary families: torus, hyperbolic and satellite.   Torus knots could be listed by the integers $(p,q)$ that specify them.  Hyperbolic knots by their volumes.  Two hyperbolic knots of the same volume would have to be sorted in some way, I'm not sure if there's a good way.  And satellite knots could be sorted lexicographically from the base of their JSJ-tree upwards.  But then this "table" would have a pretty strong bias towards the 3-manifolds view of knots.

Comment: does http://katlas.org/wiki/Main_Page help ?

Comment: @David Lehavi: No. I had this question just because that doesn't help.

@Ryan: I don't mean knots should be "periodic", but I wonder if there are better way to organize it. I just feel like some knot are not too hard to describe even if they have lots of crossings (like the torus knots), while some knots are much harder to describe in words.

BTW, your hint towards 3-manifold certainly helps.

Comment: Along the lines of Ryan's comment, here is a table of hyperbolic knots: http://www.math.unl.edu/~mbrittenham2/ldt/knots/knot11cr.ps

Comment: @temp: I think there are many productive ways to sort knots, but the way in which you sort them will be governed by what you want to *get* out of the list.  I doubt there's any kind of universal way of sorting knots that work equally well for all purposes.  Perhaps focus your question more by specifying some aspect of a sorting that you'd be interested in and there are plenty of people here who could likely help to try and fill-in the gaps. 

Comment: The following was suggested as edit "Because they have the same Alexander polynomial, which is how Rolfsen ordered, for the first time, the 10 crossing knots. --Ken Perko" at the end of second paragraph. It does not seem like a good use of  edit, so it got rejected but still I wanted to preserve the info.

Comment: Another rejected suggested edit by the same user as in quid's comment: "One cannot expect a 1-dimensional order, as for example with the periodic table of elements where protons are added one at a time. The 3-dimensional order of most of the historically tabled knots has been explained by Conway and Caudron, in examining the structure of rational and algebraic (a/k/a arborescent) knots, which have been fully classified by Schubert and Bonahon/Siebenmann, respectively. What's going on after, and along side, those two, fully understood families of knots is at the moment anybody's guess."

Comment: @Ryan Budney: just out of curiosity, is the ordering of knots by volume discrete or can accumulation points occur?

Answer (score 18):

Just for kicks, here's a partial list of various ways some people like to occasionally think of as ways of sorting knots.

- Knot energies.  For example, the electrostatic potential on knots in $S^3$ is a real-valued function on the space of knots in $S^3$ such that there's only finitely-many knot types below any given energy level.   See papers of Freedman, He and Wang, like *[Möbius invariance of knot energy](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/9301212)*, also [Jun O'Hara](http://www.wspc.com/books/mathematics/5229.html).  But there are many other knot energies out there in the literature.
- Crossing number + ??.  The traditional knot table.  Closely related are things like bridge numbers.  Minimal number of tetrahedra in a triangulation of the complement.  Stick number. Degree of a polynomial or trig function that it takes to represent the knot, and so on.
- Geometrization (as I mentioned in my comments above). See also Daniel's comment.
- Geometrization + the geometrization of the 2-sheeted cyclic branched cover of $(S^3,K)$. This is related to "arborescent knots".   Similarly, this leads to all kinds of variant ideas.  See the big paper of [Bonahon and Siebenmann](http://www-bcf.usc.edu/%7Efbonahon/Research/Preprints/BonSieb.pdf).  This is also related to rational tangle decompositions of knots.
- Braid index + a canonical form for conjugacy classes in the braid group.
- Plat closures + canonical representatives of double-cosets of the Hilden / wicket subgroup. This would be a refinement of the bridge number description.
- You could sort knots based on various knot invariants.  Alexander polynomials and Jones polynomials being fairly popular ones.

edit: Ken Perko wrote to me to object to my first comment (top of the page, before my answer).  His comment deserves a post of his own but until that happens, I'll quote him here:

> I beg to disagree with your comment that it's just based on the order
> in which they were discovered -- except, of course, for increasing
> crossing numbers tabulated by different people at different times.
>
> Tait and Little seem to have organized the order within a given
> crossing number by their own criteria of how the knots looked to them
> -- Little famously using, in his non-alternating 10-crossing  list, the so-called invariant of "twist" (now known as writhe) which placed
> the two copies of the Perko pair knots far apart from each other.
> Alexander and Briggs looked to 2-fold homology (which makes a lot of
> sense and was copied by Reidemeister) and Rolfsen used the Alexander
> polynomial, which for the first time put the Perko pair knots next to
> each other (not that that helps very much in seeing that they are the
> same). I wouldn't know how to describe the order established by
> Conway, Thistlethwaite and the rest for non-alternating 11's and 12's
> and on up, but I don't think the order of discovery had much to do
> with it.Conway followed his own peculiar patterns and Thistlethwaite
> and successors may have just left it all up to the machines,
>
> Nonetheless, your analysis is quite correct for the four knots added
> to Conway's published table and shown at the end of page 117 of
> Topology Proceedings 7 (1982). The first two were listed in D.
> Lombardero's 1968 Princeton senior thesis (of which one is the likely
> explanation for a typographical duplicate in Conway's paper) and the
> last two were discovered in the late 1970's by A. Caudron.

Comment: @David, the front page is now flooded with old questions that you have bumped up by making edits. That bumps newer questions off the front page. Please do three or four of these a day, not seventeen in a few hours.

Comment: @GerryMyerson sorry about that. I would have hoped that the variety of questions compensated for the bumping (and there is also the sort facility...), but I can definitely slow right down.

Answer (score 3):

I'm surprised no one mentioned the story by William Thompson, also known as lord Kelvin, which originally thought of atoms or elements as knots! That would literally put them in a periodic table :).

I learned this from  [this fascinating talk by Haynes Miller](https://math.mit.edu/classes/18.095/2020IAP/miller-note.pdf), which I quote the relevant part

> Thomson’s vision was that perhaps atoms consisted
> of tiny vortex rings, persistent topological singularities in the aether. Different elements
> might correspond to different knot types!—so perhaps the hydrogen atom was a simple
> loop (the “unknot”), helium was the trefoil knot, . . . .  These rings vibrated, putting them in
> different energy states. And perhaps the mystery of the formation of molecules could be
> explained by the linking of several knots to form links.

Comment: Although this is of course an interesting anecdote, the idea didn't work, so it doesn't really seem to qualify as an answer here